# Database SQL Error, Should Work

Tags: sql, database, wordpress

I'm trying to get my posts to order by radius, and so far i'm struggling, I've been using the following tut by Steve MArks, http://biostall.com/performing-a-radial-search-with-wp_query-in-wordpress

However the following code chucks up 3 errors.

```
function location_posts_where( $where )  
{  
    // Specify the co-ordinates that will form  
    // the centre of our search  
    $lat = '50.12335';  
    $lng = '-1.344453';  

    $radius = 10; // (in miles)  

    // Append our radius calculation to the WHERE  
    $where .= " AND $wpdb->posts.ID IN (SELECT post_id FROM lat_lng_post WHERE 
         ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(" . $lat . ") ) 
                        * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
                        * cos( radians( lng ) 
                        - radians(" . $lng . ") ) 
                        + sin( radians(" . $lat . ") ) 
                        * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) <= " . $radius . ")";  

    // Return the updated WHERE part of the query  
    return $where;  
}
```

The first two errors are these:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: wpdb in /home/beafweb/public_html/wp-content/themes/BEAF/functions.php on line 106

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/beafweb/public_html/wp-content/themes/BEAF/functions.php on line 106
```

Which I assume are to do with this part of the string `AND $wpdb->posts.ID` as it's on line 106.

The last error that is chucked up in the debug log is:

```
WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN (SELECT `post_id` FROM `lat_lng_post` WHERE ( 3959 * acos( cos( rad' at line 1]
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'festival-event' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND .ID IN (SELECT `post_id` FROM `lat_lng_post` WHERE ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(50.12335) ) * cos( radians( 'lat' ) ) * cos( radians( 'lng' ) - radians(-1.344453) ) + sin( radians(50.12335) ) * sin( radians( 'lat' ) ) ) ) <= 10) ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Is this linked to the first errors? seems to me that it fails to connect to the database.

I've tried backticking db parts of the string like previous threads say to, but that doesn't work either.

My knowledge of SQL isn't high but it is on my to do list, any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: The first error will be causing the 2nd error (you can see the query is missing a bit `AND .ID IN (SELECT`. My php is a little rusty. You could probably hardcode the table name by replacing `$wpdb->posts` with `wp_posts`

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely connecting to the database, otherwise you wouldn't be erroring like that.

Your DB is trying to parse your sql statement, but your database doesn't know what `$wpdb->posts.id` is since that's a PHP variable and your DB only speaks SQL.

Perhaps you should concatenate that thing into your sql statement like `$where .= " AND {$wpdb->posts}.ID IN (SELECT ...`

Comment: I think you actually want `$where .= " AND ".$wpdb->posts.".ID IN (SELECT ...`

Comment: The simpler thing to try would be `$where .= " AND {$wpdb->posts}.ID IN (SELECT ...`

Comment: That makes sense. I've updated the answer so it will actually work for OP.  I'm pretty rusty in PHP, so the help is appreciated. Thanks @AidanKane.

Comment: Ok, so i'm guessing that's an improvement as there is no errors, however it is just returning nothing now instead

Comment: Because your writing SQL dynamically in PHP, it can get tricky to diagnose. If this isn't a production system (or you don't care about garbage showing up on the page) try echoing out `$where` to your page (or the final sql statement) so you can see what this thing is spitting out and then correct it in the code.

Comment: If echo where in the page, it doesnt display anything. If i remove the `return $where` it just lists out the posts like set in the page's query

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors, what causes the third.

In your `functions.php` 106, you want to use the `$wpdb` variable, what is not in the scope of function. In the begining of your function, you need to add `global $wpdb;`

And move it outside from your string

```
$where .= " AND " . $wpdb->post->ID . " IN (SELECT post_id FROM lat_lng_post WHERE 
     ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(" . $lat . ") ) 
                    * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
                    * cos( radians( lng ) 
                    - radians(" . $lng . ") ) 
                    + sin( radians(" . $lat . ") ) 
                    * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) <= " . $radius . ")";
```

I am not sure, what's in `$wpdb` try to dump it.

Comment: I can't believe I forgot the `gobal $wpdb;` but i've made those changes and it now returns this: `Notice: Undefined property: wpdb::$post in /home/beafweb/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 675

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/beafweb/public_html/wp-content/themes/BEAF/functions.php on line 107`

Comment: and this: `WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN (SELECT post_id FROM lat_lng_post WHERE ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(50.' at line 1]
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'festival-event' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND IN (SELECT post_id FROM lat_lng_post WHERE ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(50.12335) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-1.344....`